# Best practice for code after callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm currently using node.js and one of the things it allows you to do is:

```
socket.on("sometopic", function() { 
    // this is a callback
}
```

Now let's say I have 10 different topics, each of these with one corresponding handling function that I keep in my "window", as such:

```
windows.callbacks["topic_a"] = function() {
    // code for cb a
}

windows.callbacks["topic_b"] = function() {
    // code for cb b
}

windows.callbacks["topic_z"] = function() {
    // code for cb z
}
```

And there's a piece of code I would like to have executed at the end of **every callback**. An easy way out is to create a function with this code and add a call at the end of each callback but this is far from being elegant.

Can anyone suggest a better solution for this? Is there a best practice that I'm unaware of? I'm fairly green to this kind of functional programming.

Comment: Why do you say calling another function at the end of each callback would be "far from being elegant"? Sometimes the direct approach is indeed the most readable.

Comment: Because ultimately I will have a great deal of repetition and somehow I get the feeling there should be a better mechanism for this. Something like "hey, here's the callback, and when you're done with it, execute this other function".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// THIS IS AN IDEA

// helper

function teardownWith(fn){
  return function (cb){
    return function(){
      return (cb(), fn());
    };
  };
}

// prepare a modified function

var endWithDate = teardownWith(function(){
  log(Date());
});

// pass our callback into the modified function
// endWithDate() returns the final callback.

window.callbacks["cb_a"] = endWithDate(function(){
   // code for cb_a
});
```

Comment: Interesting solution which does what I need in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the jQuery Deferred object, and adding a method to execute 'always'

[jQuery Deferred Object Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: This is an interesting jQuery feature but I'm afraid it would take too much glue code to link it to my non-jQuery code... still, it is a solution nonetheless.